# Some fields on contact page contain encoded placeholders

Tags: bug, status-review, localization, contact, html-entities

There are encoded placeholders on some fields on [contact page](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/contact). For instance:

- Trust and Safety

> [image]

- Account Issue

> [image]

Reproduced on all non-English sites if non-Latin symbols are used in resulting translations.

---

In spanish, this is what you see

[image]

Comment: in spanish is almost the same problem... the placeholders are not quite right...

Comment: It was also [reported](https://ja.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/3967) by a user of the Japanese version of Stack Overflow.